# How to unlock the endings 4 and 5 in The Uncle Who Works For Nintendo?

Tags: the-uncle-who-works-for-nintendo

I have unlocked the endings 1, 2, and 3, but I don't seem to have the patience to discover how to unlock the other two (three?), because the gameplay really gets quite repetitive.

How do I get the additional endings?